# Password Reset Logic

Tags: bcrypt, reset-password

I am implementing a password reset function. Only the Admin has the capability to reset someone's password without knowledge of their current password (or a new user).

Admin will hit reset password which will generate a token of 40 characters.
The token will be hashed with Bcrypt and stored in a DB, then the non-hashed token will be sent to the user in an email /resetPassword/tok=?

Once the user clicks the link, the token has to be validated. I am just wondering how exactly you validate the token from the link.
I know how to check to see whether it has been used, or if it has expired (48 hours). but how do you validate that it is coming from that user from that email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know how the URL was invoked. It might have happened by the user clicking on the link in the email, or it can be generated by a hacker/robot and submitted by a software or tool.

What you can do is to make sure that the email that you are using as the target, is verified. Most web applications as user to verify their email account before activating the user account (an email is sent to the user, with a token and user id and user clicks on the URL that is provided in the email). This is your way of knowing that email actually belongs to the user.

Of course, every token that you generate is saved in a table along with the intended user Id. You might have an expiry date for your tokens too.

This blog post is an excellent reference for securing the user logins and I strongly recommend it:

https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/